# Joining two 60,000 row tables together and getting 10 million rows?

Tags: mysql

Could anyone point out to me what I'm doing wrong? I'm joining up two tables which have 60,000 rows each, but when I join them it takes forever and then I end up with a table with 10 million rows?

```
CREATE TABLE VAR_PEAK AS 
              SELECT a.*, b.PKN, b.PKS
              FROM VARPEAKX a, VARPEAKZ b 
              WHERE a.ID_NO = b.ID_NO
```

Tables are identical apart from columns b.PKN, b.PKS,

The data is like this for VARPEAKX

```
ID_NO    PKNW     PKNWS  
5454      1.5      2.5
```

And The data is like this for VARPEAKZ

```
ID_NO    PKN       PKS  
5454      1.5      2.5
```

Comment: Is `ID_NO` unique in both tables?

Comment: There might be a few duplicates, but each table would have the same number of duplicates

Comment: You're getting a cartesian product of all the duplicates with each other.

Comment: Each set of duplicates will square. If you have an `ID_NO 5454` four times, you will get *sixteen* `ID_NO 5454` rows in the resulting table. To get the exact number of rows in your join, you need to find a condition that will uniquely identify each row. If you can't, there's no way for the database to know which of the `5454` rows belong together.

Comment: You need to change your `ON` condition to match all the columns that make a row unique.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, looks like it is to do with duplicates, some how I will need to filter out duplicates before I make the two seperate tables then join them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you got is just normal if you have in mind this:

> The SQL Joins clause is used to combine records from two or more
>   tables in a database. A JOIN is a means for combining fields from two
>   tables by using values common to each.

May be a schema could explain better your result with the `JOIN` keyword:

[image]

So you can get up to `3 600 000 000` (60 000 x 60 000)  rows depending on how many rows share `ID_NO`

Comment: I don't see how this explains the multiplication, which is due to the duplicate `ID_NO` values.

Comment: @Barmar his query is joining rows that have the same `ID_NO`. If you understand how INNER JOIN works you can understand he can get up to `3 600 000 000` rows, and not only one million

Answer (score -2):

The first reason it is taking for ever is that you are using cross product. That is a vary expensive operation. You should use inner or outer joins

change

```
CREATE TABLE VAR_PEAK AS SELECT a.*, b.PKN, b.PKS FROM VARPEAKX a, VARPEAKZ b 
WHERE a.ID_NO = b.ID_NO
```

to

```
CREATE TABLE VAR_PEAK AS SELECT a.*, b.PKN, b.PKS FROM VARPEAKX a inner join VARPEAKZ b 
on a.ID_NO = b.ID_NO
```

Comment: He's doing an inner join, he's just using the older, implicit join syntax instead of ANSI syntax.

Comment: This did exactly the same, got 10,844,186 results?